# Do I need to sign/encrypt cookies if I am using SSL?

Tags: cookies, encryption

If I am serving all of my web content over SSL, do I need to do another layer of encryption and sign my cookie data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SSL/TLS only offers protection against communications being intercepted and/or modified. It guarantees nothing about text files sitting on a client's hard drive (i.e. cookies).

If you want to prevent a user from presenting your web application with falsified cookie information, then yes, you need to sign your cookie data.  If you want to prevent a user from *seeing* the cookie data, then you should encrypt it as well.

Comment: Can you further explain how signing "prevent[s] a user from presenting your web application with falsified cookie information"?

Comment: @Domi Check out the Wikipedia [Digital Signature](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_signature) page. Without the private key, a user could not apply a valid digital signature to the cookie data. So the server would detect that the signature is invalid, and not trust the cookie data.

Comment: If the cookie is only a long random string, purely acting as session identifier, signing it would not add any security though, right?

Comment: @Domi `Session-Id:1234` I can change the `1234` on my hard disk to `5678`, and now I may have hijacked that session. Or something similar.  `Session-Id:1234,Signature-based-on-previous-data-and-private-key` Now, if I change `1234`, the signature is invalid. The server knows this, because he created it with a secret. Then the server knows not to trust this cookie data.

Comment: The article does not even mention siging, but there are other interesting things, I did not know yet. Thanks! Is there something like "cookie-morphing"? Where you have a client-side script to keep changing the cookie with every request, and the server also keeps track of that (with some tolerance, so that lost client requests don't disturb the protocol)?